# Best way to store an array of BitSet in database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, bitset

I got an array of `java.util.BitSet` that i want to persist in my database, but i don't know whats the best way to do it.
To be precise i got `x*y true or false` value for every entry that i want to store. I tought `java.util.BitSet` is a good call to try, but i dont really know how could i store it in database.

I'm using MySQL database with hibernate(with annotation).

This is how i initialize my map:

```
 Bitset[] map = new BitSet[x];
 for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
     map[i] = new BitSet(y);
 }
```

**Update:**

There is no relation in this dataset, and the problem is that i have tons of these "2 dimensional arrays" and one piece is around 360*180 in size.

I also tried to make an image out of it, a monochrome pbm file is easy to make. But still the data is not in the database and every time processing the saved "image" file is overkill i think and kinda slow.

Comment: what queries do you do? do you ever care how to get the ith bit? Then my reply works. If you want the whole thing at once, then you probably need to put the whole blob in the db

Comment: I want to get the whole thing out together and sometimes just few bits to say, like all 8 surrounding the one on [x,y] position. So thats why im not sure if your method is suitable for me.
But thumbs up of course, im still thinking about your method and mybe it will be fine :) thanks for the comment!

Comment: depending on the db speed that you're looking for, you might want to store the bits in different ways (all together in a blob and separate (optimized for individual bit query)). This works great for reading; if you have a lot of writes you run into consistency problems. Let me edit my reply. I just thought of something

Answer (score 2):

you could have column of ints (or whatever the equivalent is)in your database.

If you have 2 columns and assuming each column is 32 bits, you can put in 
 row 1 col 1 32 bits, then row 1 col 2 the next 32, then you go to
 row 2 col 1 and start over and so on.

Is there any relationship between these bits that you can exploit? 
 Or it's just a big dump?

Note: I used this technique to pack/compress data so it might not be exactly what you need.

**EDIT:**
 I'm thinking of storing the raw blob and tracking the *modified* bits by storing them in a separate entity (new table or more columns)
     You have the raw blob, then a mapping of `BitIndex:BitNewValue`.
     A more appropriate framework for this is now [map reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce). 
     But I can see how managing something like this can become a huge headache if many bits are changed.

Comment: Updated my question with some additional info, thanks for commenting!