# Representing a giant matrix/table

Tags: c#, oop

I need to perform calculations and manipulation on an extremely large table or matrix, which will have roughly 7500 rows and 30000 columns.

The matrix data will look like this:

Document ID| word1  | word 2  | word 3 |...  | word 30000 | Document Class
0032          1          0        0               1             P

In other words, the vast majority of the cells will contain boolean values(0's and 1's).

The calculations that needs to be done would be useing word stemming or feature selection(reducing the number of words by using reduction techniques), as well as calculations per-class or per-word etc.

What i have in mind is designing an OOP model for representing the matrix, and then subsequently serializing the objects to disk so i may reuse them later on. For instance i will have an object for each row or each column, or perhaps an object for each intersection that is contained within another class.

I have thought about representing it in XML, but file sizes may prove problematic.

I may be sitting the pot miss with my approach here - 
Am i on the right path, or would there be any better performing approaches to manipulating such large data collections.

Key issues here will be performance(reaction time etc.), as well as redundancy and integrity of the data, and obviously i would need to save the data on disk.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Is this a matrix of 7500 x 30000 numbers, or does it represent something more complicated ?  Any good answer to your question depends on more input about the contents and structure of this table or matrix.

Comment: 29998 columns will contain either 1's or 0's and the remaining two will contain strings.

Comment: if you care about storing booleans efficiently you can use them as bites and compress 32 of them in one int column. See this post I wrote http://stackoverflow.com/a/9789117/1007845

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't explained the nature of the calculations you're needing to do on the table/matrix, so I'm having to make assumptions there, but if I read your question correctly, this may be a poster-child case for the use of a relational database -- even if you don't have any actual relations in your database. If you can't use a full server, use SQL Server Compact Edition as an embedded database, which would allow you to control the .SDF file programmatically if you chose.

**Edit:**
After a second consideration, I withdraw my suggestion for a database. This is entirely because of the number of columns in the table, any relational database  you use will have hard limits on this, and I don't see a way around it that isn't amazingly complicated.

Based on your edit, I would say that there are three things you are interested in:

1. A way to analyze the presence of words in documents. This is the bulk of your sample data file, primarily being boolean values indicating the presence or lack of a word in a document.
2. The words themselves. This is primarily contained in the first row of your sample data file.
3. A means of identifying documents and their classification. This is the first and last column of your data file.

After thinking about it for a little bit, this is how I would model your data:

1. With the case of word presence, I feel it's best to avoid a complex object model. You're wanting to do pure calculation in both directions (by column and by row), and the most flexible and potentially performant structure for that in my opinion is a simple two-dimensional array of `bool` fields, like so:

   var wordMatrix = new bool[numDocuments,numWords];
2. The words themselves should be in an array or list of `string`s that are index-linked to the second column of the word matrix -- the one defined by `numWords` in the example above. If you ever needed to quickly search for a particular word, you could use a `Dictionary<string, int>`, with the key as the word and the value as the index, to quickly find the index of a particular word.
3. The document identification would similarly be in an array or list of `int`s index-linked to the first column. I'm assuming the document ids are integer values there. The classification would be a similar array or list, although I'd use a list of `enum`s representing each possible value of the classification. As with the word search, if you needed to search for documents by id, you could have a `Dictionary<int, int>` act as your search index.

I've made several assumptions with this model, particularly that you want to do pure calculation on the word presence in all directions rather than "per document". If I'm wrong, a simpler approach might be to drop the two-dimensional array and model by document, i.e. a single C# `Document` class, with a `DocumentId`, and `DocumentClasification` field as well as a simple array of booleans that are index-linked to the word list. You could then work with a list of these `Document` objects along with a separate list of words.

Once you have a data model you like, saving it to disk is the easiest part. Just use C# serialization. You can save it via XML or binary, your choice. Binary would give you the smallest file size, naturally (I figure a little more than 200MB plus the size of a list of 30000 words). If you include the Dictionary lookup indexes, perhaps an additional 120kB.

Comment: Would SQL server be able to hold a table that large?

Comment: The rows are no problems, but the columns would be a problem, and I unfortunately didn't think of that when I made this recommendation.

Comment: Your recommendation have cleared it up a great deal.. Thank you. I like both suggestions, that is the 2dim array as well as the "per document" model, which will decrease filesize definitely, because as I understand you suggest that only the words which ARE included(=1) will be referenced in the class. As for the 2dim array, do you think a 64bit system will be able to reference/hold the whole array at once in memory? And will it affect performance? Thanks again

Comment: The memory footprint of the model I gave you is 225000000 bytes for the wordMatrix, plus the size of 30000 words (that, obviously, depends on the size of the words, but if you assume an average of, say, 10 letters per word, it's around 300000 bytes more). Most modern computers can handle 250MB without breaking a sweat.